# how to extend MockWebServiceServer to perform other assertions?

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-test

I have a flow that ends with sending a SOAP request. I'd like to write some kind of integration tests, for which I give 10 elements in input, and after going through the flow, I validate that 4 requests were fired for the 4 elements I expect (the 6 others got filtered and didn't make it through).

I'm using WebServiceTemplate, and I've read about MockWebServiceServer, but I am not sure it allows to do it out of the box. I'd like to maybe extend it, so that all sent requests are saved in a List that I can access to perform the assertions. I've looked at the source code, of MockWebServiceServer / MockWebServiceMessageSender but I don't see where I would do it.

Any ideas of how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to extend RequestMatcher, not MockWebServiceServer. Here's an example of the class :

```
public class NeverFailingRequestMatcherWithMemory implements RequestMatcher {

   List<WebServiceMessage> sentRequests=new ArrayList<WebServiceMessage>();


   @Override
   public void match(URI uri, WebServiceMessage request) throws IOException, AssertionError {

       sentRequests.add(request);

   }

   public void clearMemory(){
      sentRequests.clear();
   }

   public List<WebServiceMessage> getSentRequests(){
       return sentRequests;
   }

}
```

And you use it like this in your tests :

```
    NeverFailingRequestMatcherWithMemory matcherWithMemory=new NeverFailingRequestMatcherWithMemory();

    @Before
    public void configureMockWsServer() {

        WebServiceTemplate usedWebServiceTemplate = appCtx.getBean(WebServiceTemplate.class);
        mockServer = MockWebServiceServer.createServer(usedWebServiceTemplate);

        matcherWithMemory.clearMemory();
    }
```

and later in your tests, something like :

```
mockServer.expect(matcherWithMemory).andRespond(withPayload(someResponsePayload));
assertThat(matcherWithMemory.getSentRequests()).hasSize(1);
```

Then you have access to the requests that were sent and can parse them the way you want.